# How to update the owner of the file with rsync?

Tags: rsync, ownership

I used the rsync to copy files from a remote location. After the copy, on the destination server, the files has different ownership. How can I use the rsync to update the ownership of the files? (preserve the origin)
thx, István They have different UID and GID (different user).

Comment: Are the UIDs and GIDs the same on both machines?

Answer (score 0):

- check the `-o` and `-g` flags:

  ```
  -o, --owner                 preserve owner (super-user only)
  -g, --group                 preserve group
      --devices               preserve device files (super-user only)
      --specials              preserve special files
  ```
- You can also use `-a`

  ```
   -a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
       --no-OPTION             turn off an implied OPTION (e.g. --no-D)
  ```

  since that is for "archive" and include the `-o` and `-g`. Mind the "super-user only".

For more info type [man rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) on command line or click the link.

Comment: Will it copy the files again?